# DispatcherTimer does not showing UI manipulation in tick event - UWP

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, dispatchertimer

I have a `DispatcherTimer` in my UWP app for updating database from a web services.

```
public DispatcherTimer SessionTimer { get; set; }
```

Before updating the DB in the tick event of this timer, I collapse main grid and show updating message and after update completed I do reverse.

```
private void SessionTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    rpWait.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
    LayoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    Update();
    rpWait.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    LayoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

My XAML codes:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource backGrid}">
<RelativePanel Style="{StaticResource rpTop}">
 ...
</RelativePanel>
<Frame x:Name="frameBody" Loaded="frameBody_Loaded" Margin="0,100,0,0"/>
</Grid>

<RelativePanel x:Name="rpWait" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <StackPanel  RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True">
         <TextBlock x:Name="lbMessage" FontSize="30"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">Updating</TextBlock>
         <TextBlock x:Name="lbWaiting" FontSize="30" Margin="0 50 0 0">Please Wait</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</RelativePanel>
```

But the timer does not show anything (DB updated properly).

Help me please?

Comment: I guess `LayoutRoot` is the *parent* of `rpWait`?

Comment: No, it's a sibling of rpWait.

Comment: show the XAML code, please?

Comment: OK, XAML codes is added.

Comment: What if you initially set rpWait as visible and LayoutRoot  as invisible. Without the DispatcherTimer's tick, can you get the desired effect?

Comment: The screen will only update when the UI thread is *not* executing the Tick event handler.  Technically you could force Update() to render the visual tree but then you still can't see it, human eyes cannot perceive code that takes a millisecond.  You'll have to re-think this.

Comment: Do you start your DispatcherTimer?

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. That's reasonable. I get what you say and understand my fault. Now I'm looking for new solutions. Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you dont run Update() Asynchronous and await for the update. Also if if you do UI updates better to do them in the UI thread.

```
DispatcherTimer ds = new DispatcherTimer();

// In Constuctor of the page

ds.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
ds.Tick += ds_Tick;
ds.Start();

void ds_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            ShowHide(true);
            await Update();
            ShowHide(false);
        }

private async void ShowHide(bool state)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        if(state)
        {
             rpWait.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
             LayoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            rpWait.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            LayoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    });
}

private Task Update()
{
    //run your update
    //if your update doesnt have await use
    //return Task.Run(() => {
    //            //doto
    //        });
    //If it does just write your code
}
```

Comment: Maybe the insert happents too fast? Try adding Task .Sleep(5000) below insert and check agian.

Comment: No It's take 2 minutes.

Comment: I ll ask again, do you do the insert async? if you put a breakpoint at start of method and do 'step over' will it pass Insert instantly or will wait for it to finish? and then swap visibilitys again